# Can you 'use' a macro with a listbox? VBA Excel Userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I would like to use a 'listbox' to give the user of a userform a fixed list of 'options' to choose from. I have the information in the worksheet on a separate sheet but can i use a macro to assign the range of data or will i need to specify the range with vba code?

Thanks in advance.
o/

Comment: I'm not sure what you question actually is.  A macro and VBA are the same thing when it comes to Excel.  What have you tried?  Where is your code breaking?   A review of this link may help you get the answers you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sure you can use a macro. Just call the `AddItem`-method of the listbox. Don't forget to call `Clear` before you fill the list

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ListBox on an actual UserForm, it is easiest to define the items directly in the user form's code behind. In VBA, right click on the user form, go to 'View Code' and specify your list of options e.g. in the initialize function:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With ListBox1
        .List = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A6").Cells.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

You can also specify a multi-column range:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With ListBox1
        .List = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B6").Cells.Value
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .ColumnWidths = "40;20"
    End With
End Sub
```

It is also possible to assign the list within a macro. Just make sure you assign the list between loading and showing the form.

```
Public Sub MyMacro()
    Load UserForm1
    UserForm1.ListBox1.List = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A6").Cells.Value
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

If you instead have a ListBox (Form Control) which is embedded in a worksheet, you can specify a worksheet range without VBA. Simply right-click on the listbox, select 'Format Control', and specify 'Input range' on tab 'Control'.